# How to make taskbar panel showing in Firefox at FullScreen?

Tags: firefox, xfce, fullscreen

To use full-screen in FF most of the time by hitting F11 is very usefull especially for a multi-tasking user who uses every single inch of his screen and don't want to get out of this full screen mode just to access the Xfce panel or taskbar.

Is there anyway to have both full screen for FF and a visible or auto hide taskbar panel simultaneously?

P.S. I'm using the latest Ubuntu 14.04 X64, Xfce Desktop and latest official FF (v38)

**Edit:**

I already tried other suggestions for others OSes, also Lock panel and auto show/hide panel options without effect, the nearest solution was the `xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu` keyboard shortcut but it still doesn't show the panel.

[image]

Comment: Havent tried this, but I was thinking of a combination of the addons: "hide tittlebar plus" and "the fox only better" to hide most of the firefox gui, withouth having to use fullscreen and withouth hiding XFCE panel in the procces.

Comment: I already tried both addons but that combination made my firefox very slow even on a Core I5, 6GB Ram laptop with only few tabs open, when I removed the addons it was fixed, then full-screen + autohide panel would fit perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [it is said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155037/how-to-navigate-the-panel-by-keyboard-to-launch-applications-in-xfce4) to be impossible to navigate Xfce panel, the default behaviour to cycle windows in Xfce can already show the taskbar while running an application at fullscreen.

**Default behaviour**: My own experience is quoted as follows.

> Simply invoke <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and switch to other application window. The Xfce panel will automatically get focused and will remain *on top* of already-fullscreen Firefox.

That will work even without window button or window menu applet, as long as user switch to other *non-fullscreen* application window.

**Alternative method**: Use Xfce desktop manager command with the following option.

```
-W, --windowlist
       Causes an already-running instance of xfdesktop to pop up the
       window list menu at the current position of the mouse cursor.
```

Go to **Settings > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts** and click **Add** to include this command `xfdesktop --windowlist` to the shortcut list with keyboard shortcut of your choice. Then invoke the shortcut and you have a small popup, showing the list of window at any visible area.

The alternative method will not show the Xfce panel, but allows you to switch to other windows without using the popup dialog to cycle windows.

Either way would be useful enough to do multitasking in Xfce.

Answer (score 0):

**Use "undecorate" instead.** Fullscreen mode means reducing the window's titlebar by merging it into the tab bar, and to remove the window manager panel. (At least in my Firefox version, tab bar and address bar keep displaying in fullscreen mode.) So what you want is just the first part, removing the window title bar. You can achieve this without messing with fullscreen settings, by simply removing window decorations from Firefox.

**Advantages and disadvantages.** With this solution, window titlebar buttons will not be present, unlike in "real" fullscreen mode, but you can get them back by re-decorating the window. The advantage is, you keep your fullscreen mode unchanged for use when doing presentations etc..

**Adding a keybinding.** Xfce will have a way to trigger toggling window decorations with a keybinding. I use <kbd>F12</kbd> for this, remembering it as a "special" mode for fullscreen-like behavior, one after Firefox's <kbd>F11</kbd> keybinding for normal fullscreen mode.